# Set date and time in Spring mvc

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jsp

I'm using latest spring and hibernate. I need to get the date and time form jsp page and want to insert into mysql database. I'm using **TIMESTAMP** as dataType of one fields. When I try to save, there is no error, but showing "*HTTP Status [400] – [Bad Request]*".

Finally I find out, there is a problem in **Date and Time format** (may be in **annotation or MySQL datatype or jsp page**). Because I try to update the form without changing valuei of date time (*path="startDateTime"*). It was successfully updated. When I try to change the value in date time *(path="startDateTime"*), it shows the "*HTTP Status [400] – [Bad Request]*".

I need to update Date and Time to database. I tried a lot of ways, but failed.

## Model class

```
public class Survey{

//other declaration

    @Column(name="startDateTime",columnDefinition="TIMESTAMP")      
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")
    private Date startDateTime;
}
```

## jsp page

```
<spring:url value="/survey/save" var="saveURL"></spring:url>
<form:form action="${saveURL}" method="POST" modelAttribute="surveyForm">
//other stuffs
<form:input type="datetime-local" path="startDateTime" />
</form:form>
```

## Controller

```
public ModelAndView saveSurvey(@ModelAttribute("surveyForm") Survey survey) {       
    surveyService.saveOrUpdate(survey);
    return new ModelAndView("redirect:/survey/list");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to adopt good practice, i suggest using JAVA 8 LocalDateTime class. 
So modify your model class like this

```
public class Survey{

//other declaration

    @Column(name="startDateTime",columnDefinition="TIMESTAMP")      
    private LocalDateTime startDateTime;
}
```

When using JAVA 8 LocalDateTime class, you no longer need to add `@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)`

After that,you need to create a LocalDateTimeConverter class by implement Converter interface like this

```
import org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public final class LocalDateTimeConverter implements Converter<String, LocalDateTime> {

    private final DateTimeFormatter formatter;

    public LocalDateTimeConverter(String dateFormat) {
        this.formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(dateFormat);
    }

    @Override
    public LocalDateTime convert(String source) {
        if (source == null || source.isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        }

        return LocalDateTime.parse(source, formatter);
    }
}
```

Then register the LocalDateTimeConverter class in your configuration class like this

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.format.FormatterRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
class WebMvcContext extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {
        registry.addConverter(new LocalDateTimeConverter("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS"));
    }
}
```

That's all and i hope it solves your problem.
You can learn more [here](https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-from-the-trenches-using-type-converters-with-spring-mvc)

Well, i will still like to suggest that instead of leaving the responsibility to your site user to do the date time update why not allow hibernate to do that for you by using the `@CreationTimestamp` and `@UpdateTimestamp` annotations of hibernate or preferably by using JPA `@PrePersist` and `@PreUpdate` annotations like this

```
@Column(name="startDateTime")      
@PrePersist
private LocalDateTime startDateTime;

@Column(name="updatedDateTime")      
@PreUpdate
private LocalDateTime updatedDateTime;
```

With this approach, you no longer need to add startDateTime field in your form because hibernate will automatically insert and update those columns for you.

Note: Form input type datetime-local is not supported in all browers.

Comment: As you mentioned in note, input type datetime is no longer available in jsp. So how can I get date and time? I need to set date and time, I dont need hibernate to update. So no need of `@PreUpdate`, right?

Comment: I doubt the problem is JSP related. Form input type datetime-local is not supported in Firefox and Internet Explorer 12 and its earlier versions. I suggest you use jquery datetime picker to get date and time. If the jquery datetime picker does not get datetime in ISO format, you will need to implement Converter interface and register the class like I stated in my answer otherwise you don't need to

Comment: `public ModelAndView saveSurvey(@RequestParam("startDateTime") String startDateTime){
LocalDateTime  lds = LocalDateTime.parse(startDateTime);` this methos is converting String to date. But when I use `public ModelAndView saveSurvey(@ModelAttribute("surveyForm") Survey survey) {`, it does not work

Comment: That's exactly the reason you should implement Converter interface and then register the class that implements it in your configuration class like I started in my answer. That way @ModelAttribute("surveyForm") Survey survey will work for you

Comment: Actually I've done. But it does not go inside `public ModelAndView saveSurvey(@ModelAttribute("surveyForm") Survey survey) {` . But I tried to print dates inside `LocalDateTimeConverter ` class. When I submit the button, its working fine, means its printing the date and time. But it does not compile the method. So I think, `Survey survey` object does not set value. Is there any annotation I forgot? As you said I used `private LocalDateTime startDateTime;`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the parameter send to spring mvc is String, your dateToday type is date. Spring mvc don't know how to convert it.

You need a  @InitBinder
Consult below

```
@InitBinder  
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {  
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");  
    binder.registerCustomEditor(Timestamp.class, new CustomDateEditor(dateFormat, false));  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your hibernate configuration file .xml, is it set to update? Try checking on it.

> `<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>`

Answer (score 0):

Use initbinder in your controller class

```
@InitBinder
public void dataBinding(WebDataBinder binder) {
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new 
        SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS");
    dateFormat.setLenient(false);
    binder.registerCustomEditor(LocalDateTime.class, "startDateTime", new CustomDateEditor(dateFormat, true));
}
```

Hope this solves it